# groovy.xml.Dombuilder deletes my standalone='yes', which i need

Tags: xml, parsing, groovy

As shown by this little snippet:

```
import groovy.xml.*


def xml = '''<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
    <Data>
        <![CDATA[ Test 123 ]]>
    </Data>
    '''
def document = DOMBuilder.parse( new StringReader( xml ) )
def root = document.documentElement
def result = XmlUtil.serialize( root )
println document.getXmlStandalone()
println result
```

The result is true but it prints the whole thing without standalone='yes', which I definitely need for further processing. I tried to set it true but the whole thing seems to be not well implemented... Maybe somebody can help me out here?

Comment: The standalone attribute only makes sense if you are using a DTD. It may be that without a DTD the serializer assumes it is not needed

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can with `XmlUtil`, as it just write out a generic declaration.

You can however roll your own serialization:

```
import javax.xml.transform.*
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult
import groovy.xml.*

def xml = '''<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
            |<Data>
            |    <![CDATA[ Test 123 ]]>
            |</Data>'''.stripMargin()

def document = DOMBuilder.parse( new StringReader( xml ) )

String result = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().with {
    setOutputProperty( OutputKeys.INDENT, 'yes' )
    setOutputProperty( OutputKeys.STANDALONE, 'yes' )

    new StreamResult( new StringWriter() ).with { result ->
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource( document )
        transform( source, result )
        result.writer.toString()
    }
}

println result
```

Which prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Data>
    <![CDATA[ Test 123 ]]>
</Data>
```